# Retrofit and Wikipedia API

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, wikipedia

*Hi there,*

I am making an Android application, which returns a random content from several APIs with using Retrofit2 and Gson.

I've figured it out for OMDB API. Now I am trying to make it working also for Wikipedia API. But only what I can receive are empty answers.

The code below is a working solution for OMDB API and when I simply exchange base URL, an endpoint address and copy new POJO class, it does not work. These changes from working OMDB solution to Wiki non-working solution are marked in code as well.

There is only one query called **id**.

**RestInterface class:**

```
public interface RestInterface {
@GET("/?&plot=short&r=json")                    //for Wiki I used this address: "/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&list=&meta=&explaintext=1"
Call<Model> getData(@Query("i") String id);     //for Wiki I used this query @Query("pageids")
}
```

**RestInterfaceService class:**

```
public class RestInterfaceService {

private RestInterface restInterface;

public RestInterfaceService() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://www.omdbapi.com")  //for Wiki I used this url "https://en.wikipedia.org"
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    restInterface = retrofit.create(RestInterface.class);
}

public void getData(String id, Callback callback) throws IOException {
    restInterface.getData(id).enqueue(callback);
}}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
private void getData(String id) {

    try {
        restInterfaceService.getData(id, new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {

                Model model = (Model) response.body();

                //what to do, there for example popullating one TextView                   
                final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                textView.setText(model.getTitle());     // getTitle() method is located in both of POJO classes (OMDB and Wiki)
                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            // some action
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    }
```

For better clarity I did not copy whole POJO classes here, but you can see them on these links:

- OMDB - [POJO Model.class](http://pastebin.com/fQKreXi8)
- Wiki - [POJO Classes](http://pastebin.com/x2UNtpQV) (consist of 4 classes)

For Wiki solution, I created all 4 classes and as Model.class I renamed the class called _21721040 (that class where the desired method "getTitle() is located)

Thank you all in advance,
Michalson

**Edit:** I tried to use this API (restcountries.eu/) for a check if my code will work with another api and it worked.

Comment: [Link to the Wiki API in a sandbox.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&list=&meta=&pageids=21721040&exchars=250&exintro=1&exsectionformat=plain)

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Watch - It says [pageids: A list of page IDs to work on. Separate values with |. No more than 50 (500 for bots) allowed. Type: list of integers]. Maybe you should use page ids property with int rather than string.

Comment: @SuhyeonLee Thank you, I changed the data type of id to integer in all occurrences, but unfortunately, it didn't help.

I am wondering if I should use all the POJO classes from Wiki API, because in java code there is used only one - the Model class (original name from JSON2POJO was _21721040) .

Comment: I suppose, that there is an issue with nested/multiple JSON.